# Proving the continuity of a function related with a equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have been working on the following equation:

> $e^x+x^3+x+cos(x)=d$, $d\in\mathbb{R}$

I have proven that it has unique solution by Bolzano's Theorem for each $d$, and now I want to prove that if I call $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ to the function that for all $d\in\mathbb{R}$ associates each $d$ with the unique solution of the equation, named as $g(d)$, then $g$ must be a continuous function. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First observe that $g$ is bounded on bounded intervals. This follows from the fact that the left side of the equation tends to $\infty$ as $ x \to \infty$ and it tends to $-\infty$ as $ x \to -\infty$.

Now note that $d_n \to d$ and $g(d_n) \to C$ implies that  $g(d)=C$ (by taking limits in the given equation). These facts imply, by  a standard argument using Bolzano-Weirstrass Theorem that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: Is $C$ a constant?

Comment: Yes, $C$ is a real number. There were some typos and I have corrected them. @KingSlayer